# Limit Lambda concurrency on function level with CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I want to limit the max concurrency for a specific lambda function. According to this [post](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/set-concurrency-limits-on-individual-aws-lambda-functions/), it should be possible. However, I cannot find any option for that in CDK, and most of the information point to provisioned concurrency, which is almost the opposite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can control this with the [`reservedConcurrentExecutions` prop](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda.Function.html#reservedconcurrentexecutions) of the `Function` construct.

[Documentation explaining the behavior of this parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-concurrency.html#reserved-and-provisioned)

Comment: Thanks, I should have read more carefully.

Comment: I don’t think this is correct.  As the name suggests, this _reserves_ concurrency; it makes sure that other lambdas cannot eat up all the concurrency-units.  This lambda can still eat up other units thought.

Comment: @MichaelLorton interesting - feel free to add an answer, but include links to docs

Answer (score 1):

If the lambda is being triggered by an SQS subscription, Amazon added a `MaxConcurrency` property to the [SqsEventSourceOptions construct](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda_event_sources.SqsEventSourceProps.html). This helps to prevent re-queued and DLQ'd messages by limiting the number of in flight messages rather than terminating Lambda instances.

The update is documented [in the AWS Blogs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-maximum-concurrency-of-aws-lambda-functions-when-using-amazon-sqs-as-an-event-source/). Note this specifically limits concurrency at the subscription level and **not** the function level as originally asked. (Thanks to gshpychka for pointing this out)

Comment: This is only relevant when using SQS as an event source and only applies the limit per each individual source. The accepted answer is still the correct way to limit maximum lambda concurrency in general. The question was about limiting on a function level, which your answer does not address.

Comment: Now that you point it out, I do see that the question _specifically_ mentions concurrency on the function level. I added an answer to this question because it led me to implementing an SQS triggered lambda in this way and the MaxConcurrency property (which required me to update the AWS-CDK package reference to "discover") option was pointed out by another developer on peer review.

Comment: Sure, it's a cool feature, but unrelated to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you *cannot* control this!

[`reservedConcurrentExecutions`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda.Function.html#reservedconcurrentexecutions) as the name suggests, reserves concurrency; it makes sure that other lambdas cannot eat up all the concurrency-units. <s>This lambda can still eat up other units though.</s>  *@gshpychka (Слава Україні!) points out that contrary to my initial interpretation, this number is both a minimum and a maximum for the concurrency-units.

When you queue a message in SQS for a lambda, you [can set the concurrency-limit](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-maximum-concurrency-of-aws-lambda-functions-when-using-amazon-sqs-as-an-event-source/) ... but the limit has to be at least 2, which makes it almost pointless, because you still have to manually guard against race-conditions.  I suppose certain kinds of race-conditions require three competitors, and you can ignore those, but in most cases, yeah, you are on your own.

Benjamin Franklin [said](https://loc.gov/loc/lcib/0601/franklin.html) “Three may keep a secret, if two of them are dead” and something similar can be said about lambdas: three lambdas can access a resource, if two of them have been shut down.

Comment: The documentation says that it *cannot* eat up any other units above its reserved concurrency: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-concurrency.html#reserved-and-provisioned

Comment: You might want to edit/remove the answer - you can indeed control this and the accepted answer should be correct, unless I'm still missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda has introduced a new property to solve this issue:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-maximum-concurrency-of-aws-lambda-functions-when-using-amazon-sqs-as-an-event-source/

The document also discussing why you shouldn't use the reserved concurrency.